# Why dockerized Java app doesn't terminate on exception

Tags: java, docker, exception

I have a java app running as PID 1 in an *anapsix/alpine-java:8* docker image based container. In most cases when an exception occurs the app terminates and so does the container. I noticed yesterday that an instance of this app threw an exception in *"main"* thread but didn't terminate for hours.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.BrokerNotFoundException: Could not find any available broker. Check your StreamsConfig setting 'bootstrap.servers'. This error might also occur, if you try to connect to pre-0.10 brokers. Kafka Streams requires broker version 0.10.1.x or higher.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsKafkaClient.ensureOneNodeIsReady(StreamsKafkaClient.java:251)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsKafkaClient.getAnyReadyBrokerId(StreamsKafkaClient.java:280)
        ...
```

I took a stack dump using *"kill -3 1"*. I don't see *"main"* thread in the stack dump. Also, *"DestroyJavaVM"* was created, which if I understand correctly, only happens after *"main"* exits.

```
"DestroyJavaVM" #33 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbf2400c800 nid=0x32 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

My question is, why didn't this instance terminate? I've tried to reproduce this a few times by making this app thrown exception in *"main"* thread. Every time, the app terminates as expected. Full stack dump can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/SrikanthTati/cd790a1dbaa86bdf561610faf8c12072)